# How to sum plabel value?

Tags: netlogo

I have created a NetLogo world. Agents can visit green patches, and plabel will show the visit times on each green patch. It works now. However, how could I sum all visits of each green patch after simulation? Something should be like:

```
to count-number

   ask patches [

      if plabel > 0 and pcolor = green and pycor >= -2 [

      show sum [plabel] of patches
     ]
   ]

end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 to count-number
  show sum [plabel] of patches with [ plabel > 0 and pcolor = green and pycor >= -2]
 end
```

Your code ask to every patch to print the sum of the labels of every patch but you need this to be done just once.

The `plabel > 0` part is also useless since a patch with `plabel = 0` will add 0 to the sum.